# How can we launch chrome browser with particular profile

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario to automate where I have to open profile 5 because this profile is loaded with some extension so that I want to launch it, because when we launch new chrome browser and than load the extension it is giving an error "your browser is managed by administrator"
And when I asked to admin please disable it they denied, than I am looking the work around for profiling

It would be great if can anyone provide the solution

I am expecting, that chrome profile should be launched which has this particular extension by using java selenium

Answer (score 0):

I just spent an hour searching for this yesterday and finally found it.

I had an issue with Chrome when multiple user profiles were open. Strangely enough, installing **Chrome Beta** fixed it for me!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time 

# Set up WebDriver options
options = Options() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\yourusername\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome Beta\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default or profile 5")
 
# Use webdriver_manager to automatically install the correct ChromeDriver
driver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Set up the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service, options=options)

driver.get("https://twitter.com/home")
time.sleep(10) # Wait for 10 seconds
```